# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'FBLoginViewDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode6, facebook-login

For some reason I'm getting the error `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'FBLoginViewDelegate'` when trying to include the `FBLoginViewDelegate` protocol to my `ViewController` interface.

I've searched for other similar questions but most of them seem to be related to circular inclusions...I don't think that's the case for me.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, FBLoginViewDelegate>

//Properties    
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResult;

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

I'm quite new to iOS development and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add the #import<FacbookSDK/FaceBookSDK.h> in your .h file

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove and add the add the **FacbookSDK** and

make it

```
 #import<FacbookSDK/FaceBookSDK.h> in your VC.h file or .pch file (the compiler takes the Facebook delegate in all VC's)
```

finally clean and run your project, it surely works