# Cannot find protocol declaration for FBLoginViewDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I'm trying to add the FBLoginViewDelegate protocol like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;
@end
```

However, I'm getting `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'FBLoginViewDelegate'`

I've added the FBSDKLoginKit.framework to my Xcode project.

These two answers say to add **FacebookSDK.framework** to my project and import it:

[How to make Xcode find file FacebookSDK.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h)

[Cannot find protocol declaration for 'FBLoginViewDelegate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418695/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for-fbloginviewdelegate)

However, the zip that I downloaded and extracted doesn't have a FacebookSDK.framework in it. Here is what I have:

[image]

and I downloaded it from Facebook here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Or why I don't have FacebookSDK.framework? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<FBLoginViewDelegate>` to `<FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>`.

`<FBLoginViewDelegate>` is in the previous version of SDK. The current is `<FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>`

Comment: This is correct, I actually just found some info on this. Thank you. By the way, do you happen to know if profile.userId is the unique ID of the user? I will accept this answer now :)

Comment: "know if profile.userId is the unique ID of the user"?  I don't understand what do you mean? Anyway, after successfully login you can fetch info like this [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"FacebookManager Fetched User Information:%@", result);
         
       }
       else {
         NSLog(@"FacebookManager Error %@",error);
       }
     }];

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471243/getting-users-personal-info-from-facebook-in-ios